# Как семантически правильно сделать жирные ссылки?

Tags: html

В чем разница между `<a href="#"><strong>link</strong></a>` и `<strong><a href="#">link</a></strong>`?

Какой вариант считается семантически верным?

Comment: на мой взгляд, семантически верным является применение CSS

Comment: @IvanSolntsev использование CSS действительно является хорошей практикой, но называть его [использование] _исключительно_ семантически верным – неправильно. Есть CSS, а есть HTML-которые никто не отменял.

Comment: Вопрос отличный. +1

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, я и не говорил _исключительно_, это моё личное предпочтение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стандарты html ([html4.1](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nesting.html), [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content)) разрешают вкладывать inline-элементы друг в друга. Оба ваши варианта валидны. Выбор какого-либо одного - вопрос вкуса.

Если жирный стиль ссылки не несёт смыслового значения, лучше применить этот стиль через CSS.

Answer (score 1):

В W3C спецификации теги EM и STRONG вынесены в раздел Структурированный текст -> Элементы фраз.

> EM: Indicates emphasis.
>   STRONG: Indicates stronger emphasis.

Внешний вид, как будут отображаться элементы фраз, определяется браузером.   Эти теги могут учитываться, например, Text-to-Speech движками для изменения интонации или громкости голоса.
(с) [toster](https://toster.ru/q/1653)

Как можно сделать вывод, только для текста.
Я считаю, что `<a href="#"><strong>link</strong></a>` будет правильнее с точки зрения логики, и как следствие семантики.

Answer (score 1):

Сугубо имхо, но первый вариант представляется более логичным. 
Такие ссылки:

```
<a href="#"><strong>link</strong></a>
<a href="#"><strong>several words link</strong></a>
```

при необходимости (например, если завтра внезапно окажется, что, допустим, из эстетических соображений, выделять во многословной ссылке нужно только одно ключевое слово) легко и без нарушения единообразия форматирования превращаются в

```
<a href="#"><strong>link</strong></a>
<a href="#">several words <strong>link</strong></a>
```

А вот во втором случае

```
<strong><a href="#">link</a></strong>
<strong><a href="#">several words link</a></strong>
```

превратятся в

```
<strong><a href="#">link</a></strong>
<a href="#">several words <strong>link</strong></a>
```

А подобный разнобой никак не назовешь плюсом.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения SEO, по идее, не должно быть разницы. Как минимум ни в каких документах подобных упоминаний я не видел.

Кстати аналогичный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892186/html-tag-strong-and-correct-way-of-doing-things